# Adding many-to-many relationships in ember data using JSONAPI

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

If I have the following many-to-many relationship

```
// User
export default DS.Model.create({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  authorities: DS.hasMany()
});

// Authority
export default DS.Model.create({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  users: DS.hasMany()
});
```

And I add an authority to a user

```
user.get('authorities').pushObject(authority);
```

From the [JSONAPI](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating-to-many-relationships) documentation it says to use a POST request to update a hasMany relationship

```
POST /users/XXX/relationships/authorities
{
  "data": [
    { "type": "authorities", "id": "YYY" },
  ]
}
```

How can I generate this request via ember-data?

Comment: shouldn't the `searliazeHasMany` function of the json-api serializer take care of that?

Comment: Maybe but how is it called?  `user.get('authorities').save()`?

Comment: @jax that´s how its called, I´m missing a model declaration in the hasMany, should be "authorities: DS.hasMany('authority')"

Comment: @ChristianStengel, actually you don't need the model declaration, ember-data is smart enough to infer it from the property name.

Comment: OK great [hasUserTypeSubscriptionsChanged](docs)